# Transferring data with PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I'm having a few problems with my "architecture". I'm really rusty in this field.

So the code below is basically PHP that reads a database table and prints row by row (columns are "name" (text), and "votes" (int) ) with a button near each row which is named by the "name" column as in the table.

Very simple by now, works perfectly.

Now, each button should add +1 to a row in  table in the database (to votes column), by the name of the button, simple, but since the number of buttons is not constant and is changing by the number of rows in each table (dynamic), I need to create a JS event that will get a button pressed with its name/value, and call a php function (I need specifically with functions) with the name as a variable (parameter), so it will add +1 to the votes where the name is the name pressed).

```
$allsql = "SELECT * FROM `voting` ORDER BY `voting`.`groupName` DESC, `voting`.`votes` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $allsql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<form method="post" id="voting_area">';// output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row["name"];
        $votes = $row["votes"];

        echo  'name: ' .$name. ' - votes: ' .$votes. ' <button type="button" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</button><br>';

     }
    echo '</form>';
}
```

Please try and explain me specifically each code (JS, AJAX, PHP).

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Along with tadman, I'd also avoid mysqli and use PDO if it's an option.

Comment: Well, thanks I'll make the changes for the db but it's not even related to my question.

Comment: is this of any help https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: dudes, I asked about php and ajax.. @RyanGadsdon

Comment: @DanielLiverant it might be helpful to put your current results and desired results

Comment: What have you tried so far? The JS side should be reasonably simple... iterate the `<button>` elements and attach a _click_ event listener that submits an AJAX request to a PHP script with the _name_ data. That PHP script can access the request data and call your function

Comment: If you can, try to separate HTML of your PHP.